# COM servers in Delphi service applications

Tags: delphi, service, com

This is a somewhat general question but I'm hoping someone will have specific info or recommendations.

I have an application suite that includes a service application that acts as a communications interface and data historian for industrial pollution-control hardware.  The service contains a singleton COM server to allow the rest of the suite to have access to the hardware and data via the service.

I've read the stuff about how SvCom is required to make COM servers work in Delphi service apps.  I have and use SvCom - it does what it claims.  But I'm not all that comfortable with it, the product and my coding styles and expectations don't match, and it makes debugging somewhat more of a headache.

But my real problem is with the idea that the lengths SvCom goes to to make a COM server work in a service app is absolutely required.  Their documentation, and some of the stuff that comes up in searches on the subject, makes it sound like their toolbox is absolutely required for any COM-server-in-service scenario.  But I have a couple of different 3rd-party libraries for implementing OPC servers, Prosys Sentrol and the older Production Robots library (if you're not familiar with OPC, it's a pretty-much ubiquitous data-interchange standard built on COM) and both support the OPC COM server being put in standard TService-based apps without special handling beyond doing in the AfterInstall and BeforeUninstall events what would normally be done in a stand-alone EXE when run with the /regserver or /unregserver command-line switches, and of course using DelayInitialize := True.  So at least *SOME* COM servers can be done as typical TService-based apps without the extraneous steps SvCom goes through.

So my question is: Is the line between "what sorts of COM servers work in a TService-based app" and "what causes the need for the extra stuff SvCom does" clearly known?  If so, what is it and/or where is it documented?  If not, I'm kind of surprised - seems like implementing COM servers in service apps would be a fairly common need, but I've does several deep searches and, based on the dearth of info I've found on the subject, maybe it's not.

Comment: COM that doesn't deal with UI works fine in services, as long as you remember to call CoInitialize/CoInitializeEx in each thread that uses COM. You might also have to change the threading model from `tmSingle` to `tmApartment` in the call to `TComObjectFactory.Create`.

Comment: From what I remember (It's been a while) I once stumbled upon [CoInitializeSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693736%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make things work, but your milage may vary. I also remembered that I had to manually change a registry value from "LocalServer32" to "LocalService" to get COM to start my service when needed. I don't know if a lot has changed since then (Windows Vista and later with UAC, all the new Delphi versions since 7...)

Comment: I have written services (in BCB6) using the standard `TService` that host COM servers in them, and they work fine, even in modern Windows versions. SvCom is a nicety, NOT a requirement. It is not difficult to get a COM server working in a service. There are only a few things that have to be hooked up manually. Like `LocalService` (you don't change `LocalServer32`, you add `LocalService` to the standard COM registration). The only thing I ever had to change regarding the standard COM registration is to make it support registering in HKCU instead of HKLM in some cases, but that is optional.

Comment: Thanks, guys.  I'll look up the LocalService stuff.